# Amount of time for giving the date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a report in `MySQL` for consecutive days based on activity recorded. I have the start date&time and end date&time of a given status. My goal is to receive a report in a form:

`Status|Date|Sum of activity`

The problem that I've encountered is that some activities start i.e. `2019-12-12 18:21:12` and ends the next day `2019-12-13 03:21:12`. Is there a way to let's say split the result for one date until `23:59:59` and add the rest of time to the following day? So far I have a code below, but it just sums the timestampdiff.

```
USE db;
SELECT
  table1.status,
  left(table1.start_time, 7) ' Date',
  sec_to_time(
    sum(
      timestampdiff(
        second,
        table1.start_time,
        (
          case when table1.end_time is null then now() else table1.end_time end
        )
      )
    )
  ) 'Sum of activity'
FROM
  table1
GROUP by 1,2
```

**Update :** Let me clarify a bit my question. I have some activities that take for example 36 hours, starting on 2019-12-20 and ending on 2019-12-22. I need a composed monthly report with each day in the month selected from start_time, so for the example described above (36h over 3 days) I would like to get:

```
Activity1|2019-12-20|3h 
Activity1|2019-12-21|24h 
Activity1|2019-12-22|9h
```

**Update2:** Thank you for the 2nd update,but the proposed code works only for the first record in the dataset (for more records the time is not summed up) and doesn't take into account the activity type. I will provide more data maybe it will help:

```
     Activity  start_time           end_time 
     1048      2019-12-27 06:42:51  2019-12-27 07:11:42 
     1048      2019-12-29 07:07:11  2019-12-29 07:08:59 
     1048      2019-12-29 07:09:19  2019-12-29 07:21:10 
     2066      2019-12-25 07:08:00  2019-12-25 19:01:17 
     2066      2019-12-25 19:01:17  2019-12-26 06:55:15 
     2066      2019-12-26 06:55:15  2019-12-26 18:20:51
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date()` function :

```
select status, date(start_time) as date, count(*) as "Sum of activities"
  from table1
 group by status, date(start_time);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a2847d67183f79f7de9302e01b7abf4)</kbd>

**Update** (depending on your comment): Try to use

```
select status, date(start_time) as date, 
       sec_to_time(sum(timestampdiff(second,
                                     start_time,
                                     (case
                                       when end_time is null then
                                        now()
                                       else
                                        end_time
                                     end))))
       as "Sum of activities"
  from table1
 group by status, date(start_time);
```

**Update2** : To accomplish the last mentioned duty, need to generate rows firstly :

```
select date1, 
       extract( hour from
       sec_to_time(
                   sum(case
                       when date1 = date(start_time) then
                    timestampdiff(second,start_time,date2)
               when date1 = date(end_time) then
                    timestampdiff(second,date1,end_time)
               else
                    timestampdiff(second,date1,date2)              
               end     
                    )) ) as "Time Difference as hour"
  from
  (
   select @cr := @cr + 1 as rn,       
          date_sub(date(end_time), interval date(end_time)-date(start_time) - @cr + 1 day) as date1,
          date_sub(date(end_time), interval date(end_time)-date(start_time) - @cr day) as date2,
          start_time, end_time
     from information_schema.tables c1 
    cross join ( select @cr := 0 ) r
    cross join table1 t
    where @cr < date(end_time)- date(start_time)+1
  ) q
  group by date1;
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=151974beaa93656438d303d23a712761)</kbd>

removing `extract( hour from` `)` part you can get the whole difference upto second precision.

Comment: Thank you for your support! That solves the problem with using "left" function, but unfortunately for the cases when I have a long period of activity, Sum of activity for given day exceeds 24h:

2019-12-22 28:25:06

Comment: whaattt :) @Kolcz11 , how can a hour:minute:second data combination exceed 23:59:59 ? You're welcome.

Comment: It's a value recieved from sec_to_time function after getting a sum of timestampdiff of start and end date&time as from the example...

Comment: Is that really a problem?  F.e. `select sec_to_time(sec) from (select 100000 as sec) q` returns `1.03:46:40`.  So the days are there.  And there's also [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-convert-timediff-output-to-day-hour-minute-second-format)

Comment: Indeed, I couldn't percieve what OP means :) @LukStorms